# identity specification gap after several operations

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, primary-key

I'm using `identity specification` for a table in SQL Server 2012. Let we have two `Insert` and then two `Delete` operations. After these operation, the primary key should start from 1, but it will start from 3. I'm worried about this problem **causing no place for inserting new item** after a long time. Does SQL Server 2012 fill these gaps by itself?

If it is possible, please refer me a documentation (for example from microsoft)

Update 1:
I heard that it can jump randomly. Especially when server is restarted. I insert into table every 500 ms. Let, my primary key jump to 1,000,000,000. Two jump like this is enough for termination of my program.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/739013/failover-or-restart-results-in-reseed-of-identity

Comment: unless you're working with _a lot_ of data, this isn't a problem.  what data type is the primary key?  just an int?  you should be fine...

Comment: No SQL Server won't automatically reuse identity values after rows have been deleted.

Comment: @MartinSmith: and that's a **GOOD THING!** (tm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a type `INT`, starting at 1, you get **over 2 billion** possible values - that should be more than sufficient for the vast majority of cases - even if there are a few gaps.

Just think about this: if you use an `INT IDENTITY` starting at 1, and you insert a row **every second**, all day long, on every single day all year long,  you need **66.5 years** before you hit the 2 billion limit ....

With `BIGINT`, you get roughly **922 quadrillion** (922 with 15 zeros - 922'000 billions) - enough for you?? If you use a `BIGINT IDENTITY` starting at 1, and you insert **one thousand rows every second**, all day long, every day of the year, you need a mind-boggling **292 million years** before you hit the 922 quadrillion limit ....

Read more about it (with all the options there are) in the [MSDN Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx).

Comment: Or even `CREATE TABLE T(ID NUMERIC(38,0) IDENTITY)` for just under a Duodecillion values.

Comment: Just can't find any mention of "gazillion" on Wikipedia :-)

Comment: and what if my primary-key is not an integer?

Comment: @Babak.Abad: if you're using an `IDENTITY` - then you key **is** `INT` or `BIGINT` or `NUMERIC(x, 0)` .....

Comment: +1  @marc_s for sharing such interesting statistics  about int and bigint :)